# WARNING in Circular dependency detected Compiled with warnings

Tags: angular

When I am trying to my build project it throws error-

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\own-filter\own.filter.module.ts -> src\app\own-filter\own.filter.component.ts -> src\app\own-filter\own.filter.module.t

[image: Attached package.json file]

[image: Angular CLI on machine]

Thanks in Advance. Let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an import inside your `OwnFilterComponent` which imports the `OwnFilterModule`. I cannot think of a reason that you should need that. But without any actual code from you it's hard to see, why you want to import a module into a component.

To turn off this warning you have to put this line in your `.angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "defaults": {
    ...,
    "build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
  }
}
```

Only do this if you really really have no other way to resolve this circular dependency. But like I stated before, I'm pretty sure you can get around this one.

The reason it warns for this, is because a circular dependency will cause issues using the closure compiler

Comment: @PierreDuc- Could you please specify where to put above lines. i tried putting it give compile time error.

Comment: Well, inside your `.angular-cli.json` file. Obviously without the `...`, you should put `false` in `defaults.build.showCircularDependencies`